# TODO comments in NetBeans 6.9 Python

Tags: python, netbeans, comments, todo

How do I add a TODO comment in NetBeans 6.9 Python?

I have taken a look under `Tools` > `Options` > `Miscellaneous` > `Tasks`

However, when I add a comment to my source code:

```
# TODO This won't appear in the Tasks panel
```

`TODO` actually turns a different color, but the comment doesn't show up in my Tasks panel. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be [a known bug in netbeans](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63953).
Some of the people commenting on the bug point to a Netbeans plugin to solve this.

Comment: I have been through that bug report. Unfortunately, I couldn't make out which plugin is needed to fix the issue. Searching `todo` or `task` doesn't return results that are related to this. Do you happen to know what plugin is required?

Answer (score 2):

go back into tools->options->miscellaneous->tasks and uncheck "show todos from comments only".
this seems to fix the issue for php on Netbeans 7.0.1. It may also work on 6.9 for python if the option exists in that version. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks mate, worked a treat for me. I was searching for a way to make the TODO items show up as Action Items in Netbeans for my PHP projects.

Answer (score 1):

For Java project the task window works correctly. But for C++ (in my case) it doesn't work. (NetBeans 7.0.1). I think that feature is only for Java.